# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'merge')" Error when making a GET request with RTK Query

Tags: reactjs, next.js, redux-toolkit, redux-thunk, rtk-query

I'm using RTK Query to GET data from an API. I'm receiving the following error on my requests.
Below is the error message-

```
rtk-query.esm.js:1053 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'merge')
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/@reduxjs/toolkit/dist/query/rtk-query.esm.js:1074:68)
    at updateQuerySubstateIfExists (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/@reduxjs/toolkit/dist/query/rtk-query.esm.js:1014:9)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/@reduxjs/toolkit/dist/query/rtk-query.esm.js:1070:17)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/@reduxjs/toolkit/dist/redux-toolkit.esm.js:767:32)
    at produce (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/immer/dist/immer.esm.mjs:25:16108)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/@reduxjs/toolkit/dist/redux-toolkit.esm.js:766:77)
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at reducer (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/@reduxjs/toolkit/dist/redux-toolkit.esm.js:745:29)
    at reducer (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/@reduxjs/toolkit/dist/redux-toolkit.esm.js:844:20)
    at combination (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/redux/es/redux.js:571:29)
    at reducer (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/@reduxjs/toolkit/dist/query/rtk-query.esm.js:1295:53)
    at combination (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/redux/es/redux.js:571:29)
    at dispatch (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/redux/es/redux.js:299:22)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/redux-logger/dist/redux-logger.js:1:7667)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/@reduxjs/toolkit/dist/query/rtk-query.esm.js:2053:27)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/@reduxjs/toolkit/dist/query/rtk-query.esm.js:2053:27)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/@reduxjs/toolkit/dist/query/rtk-query.esm.js:2053:27)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/@reduxjs/toolkit/dist/query/rtk-query.esm.js:2053:27)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/@reduxjs/toolkit/dist/query/rtk-query.esm.js:2053:27)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/@reduxjs/toolkit/dist/query/rtk-query.esm.js:2053:27)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/@reduxjs/toolkit/dist/query/rtk-query.esm.js:2053:27)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/@reduxjs/toolkit/dist/query/rtk-query.esm.js:2053:27)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/@reduxjs/toolkit/dist/query/rtk-query.esm.js:2053:27)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/@reduxjs/toolkit/dist/query/rtk-query.esm.js:2053:27)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/@reduxjs/toolkit/dist/query/rtk-query.esm.js:2053:27)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/@reduxjs/toolkit/dist/redux-toolkit.esm.js:518:22)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/redux-thunk/es/index.js:21:16)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/@reduxjs/toolkit/dist/redux-toolkit.esm.js:429:36)
    at dispatch (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/redux/es/redux.js:702:28)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/@reduxjs/toolkit/dist/redux-toolkit.esm.js:1365:41)
    at step (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/@reduxjs/toolkit/dist/redux-toolkit.esm.js:96:23)
    at Object.eval [as next] (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/@reduxjs/toolkit/dist/redux-toolkit.esm.js:77:53)
    at fulfilled (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/@reduxjs/toolkit/dist/redux-toolkit.esm.js:130:32)
```

I'm expecting to get access to the data from the response. The data is showing in network tab in the response field of that endpoint but unable to access it in console. It's showing as undefined. All other APIs are working except the GET one.

Below is the query that's giving the error

```
getUserProfileData: builder.query({
      query: ({ user_profile_id }: any) => {
        return {
          url: `${COMMON_API_URL.getUserProfile}/${user_profile_id}`,
          method: "get",
        };
      },
    }),
```

Here is my API endpoint setup using RTK Query:

```
import { BaseQueryFn, createApi } from "@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react";
import { COMMON_API_URL } from "@/app/constants/apiUrls";
import { axiosBaseQuery } from "../../helper";

export const profileApis = createApi({
  baseQuery: axiosBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: ``,
  }),
  reducerPath: "profile",
  //keepUnusedDataFor: 0,
  //refetchOnMountOrArgChange: 10,
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getUserProfileData: builder.query({
      query: ({ user_profile_id }: any) => {
        return {
          url: `${COMMON_API_URL.getUserProfile}/${user_profile_id}`,
          method: "get",
        };
      },
    }),
    updateProfile: builder.mutation({
      query: ({ user_profile_id, data }) => {
        return {
          url: `${COMMON_API_URL.getUserProfile}/${user_profile_id}`,
          method: "put",
          data: { ...data },
        };
      },
    }),
    postProject: builder.mutation({
      query: ({ user_profile_id, data }) => {
        return {
          url: `${COMMON_API_URL.getUserProfile}/${user_profile_id}/projects`,
          method: "post",
          data: { ...data },
        };
      },
    }),
    deleteProject: builder.mutation({
      query: ({ user_profile_id, project_uuid }) => {
        return {
          url: `${COMMON_API_URL.getUserProfile}/${user_profile_id}/projects/${project_uuid}`,
          method: "DELETE",
        };
      },
    }),
    updateProject: builder.mutation({
      query: ({ user_profile_id, project_uuid, data }) => {
        return {
          url: `${COMMON_API_URL.getUserProfile}/${user_profile_id}/projects/${project_uuid}`,
          method: "put",
          data: { ...data },
        };
      },
    }),
    postExperience: builder.mutation({
      query: ({ user_profile_id, data }) => {
        return {
          url: `${COMMON_API_URL.getUserProfile}/${user_profile_id}/experiences`,
          method: "post",
          data: { ...data },
        };
      },
    }),
    deleteExperience: builder.mutation({
      query: ({ user_profile_id, experience_uuid }) => {
        return {
          url: `${COMMON_API_URL.getUserProfile}/${user_profile_id}/experiences/${experience_uuid}`,
          method: "DELETE",
        };
      },
    }),
    updateExperience: builder.mutation({
      query: ({ user_profile_id, experience_uuid, data }) => {
        return {
          url: `${COMMON_API_URL.getUserProfile}/${user_profile_id}/experiences/${experience_uuid}`,
          method: "put",
          data: { ...data },
        };
      },
    }),
    postEducation: builder.mutation({
      query: ({ user_profile_id, data }) => {
        return {
          url: `${COMMON_API_URL.getUserProfile}/${user_profile_id}/educations`,
          method: "post",
          data: { ...data },
        };
      },
    }),
    deleteEducation: builder.mutation({
      query: ({ user_profile_id, education_uuid }) => {
        return {
          url: `${COMMON_API_URL.getUserProfile}/${user_profile_id}/educations/${education_uuid}`,
          method: "DELETE",
        };
      },
    }),
    updateEducation: builder.mutation({
      query: ({ user_profile_id, education_uuid, data }) => {
        return {
          url: `${COMMON_API_URL.getUserProfile}/${user_profile_id}/educations/${education_uuid}`,
          method: "put",
          data: { ...data },
        };
      },
    }),
    updateUserProfile: builder.mutation({
      query: ({ user_account_uuid, data }) => {
        return {
          url: `${COMMON_API_URL.getUserAccount}/${user_account_uuid}`,
          method: "put",
          data: { ...data },
        };
      },
    }),
  }),
});
export const {
  useGetUserProfileDataQuery,
  useUpdateProfileMutation,
  usePostProjectMutation,
  useDeleteProjectMutation,
  useUpdateProjectMutation,
  usePostExperienceMutation,
  useDeleteExperienceMutation,
  useUpdateExperienceMutation,
  usePostEducationMutation,
  useDeleteEducationMutation,
  useUpdateEducationMutation,
  useUpdateUserProfileMutation
} = profileApis;
```

I'm querying the getUserProfileData query endpoint in a component as follows:

```
const {
    data: profileData,
    isLoading: profileLoading,
    refetch: profileRefetch,
  } = useGetUserProfileDataQuery(
    {
      user_profile_id,
    }
  );
  console.log(profileData, "dataaa")
```

Can anyone help me on this? Thanks.